# Deleting a face leaves weird ghost edges

Tags: edges

After removing a face from a box 2 ghost edges were left behind. I can't select them nor delete them using `x -> edges`.

[image]

as you can see, when I select those 2 vertices the edge between them isn't being select like it doesn't exist. How do I remove it?

Thanks!

**Blend file**: Sorry for my amateur modeling skills, that's my first model ever and I'm not following a tutorial :3

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to our stack exchange.

Do you have any modifiers on the object?  In edit mode, in some configurations you can see the modified object under the unmodified one that you're editing.  I also suggest posting your blend file to help someone answer your question faster.

Comment: Hello! I don't have any modifiers on the object. I'll post my blend file in a second @jwrush

Comment: Your model is fine, and impressive if your very first one.  Good luck and have fun with modeling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What looks like one point is actually several, all on top of each other:

[image]

This is actually a pretty common problem that happens while modeling in Blender. You can fix it by selecting all of the points on the mesh (hitting "A") and then selecting `Merge By Distance` from the `Clean Up` Menu.

[image]

You'll then be able to select and delete the edge you want to get rid of:

[image]

Comment: Well it deleted 46 vertices 0_0
How come that those vertices appeared?

Comment: Really hard to know, could be any number of things that happend, but I often find in my own case that it's from copying parts of meshes in the wrong way or even just sloppy key strokes.  If you find them on the center of the mesh (not the case here) it's usually because of mirror modifier.

Comment: Extruding and then canceling movement with right click is a common cause.